# AngularJS - Dynamically adding views along with their routes and controllers

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an application where I'll be getting JSON file containing content. From that JSON, I will create a view(html), bind it to a controller and route that are to be created when I receive the JSON. It will be a list of items where each item leads to a different view, controller and route.

I need help in implementing this dynamic behavior in the application.

Much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

**I forgot to mention that this is to be implemented in an Ionic Application**

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought...

- Remove the ng-app attribute. This will prevent angular to bootstrap
  automatically.
- Call for the JSON using `XMLHttpRequest`
- use the retrieved data in the application config to build your routes
- manually start the angular application calling `angular.bootstrap` [More](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention that the application I'm developing is on Android using Ionic Framework.